# Capture all matching patterns after a string text

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match, matching, pcre

I want to capture both values after `<ParagraphB>`, but I'm currently stuck on only capturing the last match. Here is my regex so far:

`<ParagraphB>(?s).*<value>([^\<]*)`

```
<ParagraphA>
<value>12</value>
<ParagraphB>
<value>34</value>
<value>56</value>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the value multiple times, we need to use the `global` flag and retrieve the captured group in each match.

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/1Demzp/1

**Pattern:** `(?:<ParagraphB>|\G<\/value>)\s*?<value>([^<]*)`

**Explanation:** For the first time match, `<ParagraphB>`. From next iteration, only match if the string starts with `</value>`

- `(?:<ParagraphB>|\G<\/value>)`: Match `<ParagraphB>` or string should start with `</value>`. `\G` is for [continuing matches](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).
- `\s*` : Non greedy match of any no of space characters
- `([^<]*)` : Capture all characters till `<`.